# jquery tools overlay, how to keep mask when switching overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I have a simple problem with 2 overlays. One overlay is triggered from (and by) the other overlay. As only one overlay can be active at any one time, correctly so, overlay number 1 that triggered 2 closes. However, it takes the mask with it and hence overlay 2 appears without the mask. How can I switch between 2 overlays without the mask disappearing?

The code, overlay 1

```
$("button[rel*=busy]").overlay({     

    api: true , 
    mask: {
        maskId: 'defaultMask' ,
        color: null
    },
    effect: 'apple',

    onLoad: function() {

        $.post( 'ajax_file_here.php' ,
            { var: something } ,
            function( data ){                

                if( data.status == 'confirm' ) {

                    confirmOverlay();

                } else {

                    errorOverlay();

                }              

            } ,
            'json' );

    } ,
    closeOnClick: false ,
    closeOnEsc: false ,
    close: '.noClose'       

});
```

And overlay 2

```
var errOverlayObject = $('#error_overlay').overlay({

    api: true,      
    mask: {
        maskId: 'defaultMask' ,
        color: null
    },
    effect: "apple"

});

function errorOverlay() {

    errOverlayObject.load();

}
```

As you can see there is also a confirm version of the second overlay, but that works identical to the error one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you do not mind but I created my own simplified example.  Hopefully you will be able to adapt this to your situation.

There is a little bit of flicker between the dialogue boxes (due to the animation effect) but the mask stays in place.  I imagine you could remove the flickering by adjusting the animation effect settings - I suspect you could do something in the overlay's **onBeforeLoad** method but I'm not exactly sure what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chained Modals</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .modal {
        background-color:#fff;
        display:none;
        width:350px;
        padding:15px;
        text-align:left;
        border:2px solid #333;

        opacity:0.8;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <button class="modalInput" rel="#box1">Stage 1</button>
</p>
<div class="modal" id="box1">
    <h2>Stage 1 dialogue</h2>
    <p>
        You can only interact with elements that are inside this dialog.
        To close it click a button or use the ESC key.
    </p>
    <button class="modalInput" rel="#box2">Stage 2</button>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="box2">
    <h2>Stage 2 dialogue</h2>
    <p>
        You can only interact with elements that are inside this dialog.
        To close it click a button or use the ESC key.
    </p>
    <button class="modalInput" rel="#box3">Stage 3</button>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="box3">
    <h2>Stage 3 dialogue</h2>
    <p>
        You can only interact with elements that are inside this dialog.
        To close it click a button or use the ESC key.
    </p>
    <button class="close">End</button>
</div>
<script>

$(window).load(function() {
var msk;

var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#ebecff',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9,
        onClose: function() {
            var id = this.getExposed().attr('id');
            if(id == 'box1'|| id == 'box2'){
               var nextId;
               if(id == 'box1'){
                  nextId = '#box2';
               }
               if(id == 'box2'){
                  nextId = '#box3';
               }
               msk = this.getMask();
               msk.css('display','block');
               $(nextId).css('z-index', '9999');
            }
        }
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    onBeforeLoad: function(){
        var id = this.getOverlay().attr('id');
        if(id == 'box2'|| id == 'box3'){
               // need to put something here to avoid flicker
               //
           // this.getConf().mask.startOpacity = 0.8; 
        }
    }
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It sure did. And I don't mind the flicker, as it accentuates the fact that something worthy of your attention is happening. I did simplify the onClose a little bid though, manipulating the mask and thus not needing the id part of your code, with  msk.css( { 'display' : 'block' , 'z-index' : '1000' } ); Another important little change, necessar in my code, was an onclose that closes the mask in the overlay triggers for the secondery overlays (error and confirm). But it's all working now, thanks a million!

Answer (score 6):

I think an easier way would be to

```
.overlay({
   mask: { color: '#000', opacity: '.60' },
   onLoad: function(){
       var t = $.mask;
       if(!t.isLoaded()){
            t.load();
            var ov = this.getOverlay();
            ov.css('z-index', '9999');
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add "closeSpeed: 0" into mask configuration of the first overlay and it will work.
For example:

```
    $('#login_overlay').overlay({
        top:'center',
        mask: {
            color: '#666',
            closeSpeed: 0,
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to handle separately the mask: the overlay is created without a mask, and the mask is activated separately.

Your first overlay would require a setup such as:

```
$(selector).overlay({ 
    ..., 
    onBeforeLoad: function(){
                       $(document).mask('#222'); 
                       closeMask=true;
                  },
    onClose: function(){
                       if (closeMask) $.mask.close();
                  }
);
```

Then, in order to show the second overlay, you set the closeMask variable to false. Obviously, the second overlay must hide the mask on close.